# Highcharts data module and HTML table change distribution column

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using Highcharts (http://www.highcharts.com/) with its data module (http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js) to create a data visualization and chart using HTML table.

My table consists of mixed columns with string - for distribution and numbers for values. The table is something as follows

[image]

Now, with the given HTML table, I want the user to be able to select the distribution column based on which the series in the charts are plotted. In the sense when the **Product** column is selected, the graph would appear something like

[image]

And if the **Category** column is selected it would be something like

[image]

Essentially in this example, the labels in the X-Axis are changed. Although, there are cases when the graph itself would change when the distribution changed.

**Progress So Far: -**

I have managed to find out that there is a start column and end column which can be defined based on which the distribution column and the values can be identified. Although, this does not traverse the whole table to get the exact results.

I used the following code (Available on http://jsfiddle.net/3Ezjj/) for making the distribution column as *Category* and the next column as the value: -

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        data: {
            table: document.getElementById('datatable'),
            startColumn: 0,
            endColumn: 1
        },
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Data extracted from a HTML table in the page'
        },
        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            title: {
                text: 'Units'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                    this.point.y +' '+ this.point.name.toLowerCase();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide the Highcharts API link to the attributes "startColumn" and "endColumn" ?

Comment: @RahulGupta, There is no concrete documentation on the Highcharts site. Although, you can get some info on a Beta version of the plugin file here - http://github.highcharts.com/v3.0Beta/modules/data.js.
**EDIT**
Here is a link to one of Highcharts demo where startColumn and startRow is used - http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/us-data-labels

Comment: Because of lack of documentation I cannot get a proper idea of these options. According to you how these options can help in solving your problem ?

Comment: I would suggest you to create two separate maps for Category and Product and perform show/hide based on user's selection

Comment: @RahulGupta, That is one option. But the challenge is that the table which I have showed here is just a stub. This might be a lot bigger and with a mix of string and integer based columns.

Comment: @RahulGupta, can you please answer to this question so that I can accept it. I went with the hide/ show approach which you have mentioned :-)